# Replacing form controls in vb6

Tags: vb6, controls

We have an in house button control, and quite frankly it sucks.  I'd like to replace it but I don't want to go onto every form in our project and delete/add a new control.  It seems to me that if I design a new button that has all the same properties as the old one then I ought to be able to give it the same name as the old one and just replace all the reference lines in the vbp files to point to the new control.

Has anyone tried this (better yet have you heard of a tool that will do it for you) and if so what 'gotchas' should I be on the look out for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *.vbp files are one place you'll need to change. There are also references to the used control libraries in the files containing GUIs -- that's form (*.frm), control (*.ctl), and property page (*.pag) files. These files are in a plain text format and you can see the references at the top. They look like this:

```
Object = "{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0"; "mscomctl.ocx"
```

Those refs will need to be added or updated in all relevant files if the new control is a compiled OCX. If it's in the same project I don't think it needs any reference there, and if it's in a different project in the same project group I'm not sure. Save a test form with the new control to see.

Note that you don't have to keep the same control class name. Inside the *.frm/ctl/pag files, instances of individual controls on them are represented by a simple format like this:

```
Begin VB.CommandButton Command2 
   Caption         =   "Cancel"
   Height          =   375
   Left            =   2460
   TabIndex        =   1
   Top             =   2400
   Width           =   1455
End
```

The syntax of the first line there is "Begin LibraryOrProjectName.ClassName NameOfThisInstance". So, provided the offending control's name is distinctive it should be easy to search & replace references to it both in the BASIC source and in the GUI layouts. You might want a plain text editor that can perform search and replace across multiple files (Notepad++ is one).

Some control properties are stored like this:

```
   Picture         =   "frmMain.frx":292F
```

These correspond to the *.frx, *.ctx, and *.pgx files, which contain binary data for the values of certain control properties. I don't think these files should need altering or cause any problems. They don't appear to contain control names.

Use a full compile (Ctrl+F5) to be sure no problems linger in parts of the source afterward.

Never tried it. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I totally forgot to mention updating the forms but I did know that.  I definitely could rename the controls but they are generally named appropriately so there's not much reason to do that.  You do bring up a good point about the properties that reference the frx.  The new control I want to use is actually a .net interop dll, so I wonder if there's a way to preserve the pictures currently referenced in the frx?

Comment: It's a touch screen pos app, so 9 out of 10 buttons have pics on them.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: That's unfortunate. I don't know about .NET interoperation. I didn't even know you could use a .NET control on a VB6 form. If the new control's picture property is a VB6 `IPictureDisp` or `StdPicture` that will probably be stored the same as the original control, but I think it's entirely up to the control how it internally reads and writes its stuff -- it does not have to be consistent with how its properties are accessed normally. You might have to do the pictures manually.

Comment: That's a good point.  I bet if I could make them IPictureDisp's they would work perfectly.  I don't believe the control itself does anything with the frx, I think vb6 just uses that info to populate the property for you.  However, I think I just thought of a better idea.  It wouldn't take much to modify the existing button to just store a filename and then I wouldn't need a IPictureDisp at all.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: Controls don't access the frx themselves, but VB doesn't populate the properties either; it uses the frx to populate the PropertyBag object. It's up to the control how it organizes data in the property bag, and that need not (though almost always does) correlate with the visible properties. A file name would certainly interop nicely but a standard picture property is just an in-memory object with no referenced file, so unless your current button is different in that way you'd still have to set the file name on all of the existing buttons manually to do that.

Comment: Actually, I guess you could modify the old button to read a picture OR file from its property bag but save a (newly created) file name. Then do a dummy save on all the forms to run that conversion code.

Comment: Yeah it's all coming back to me now that you mention that. I've created a few vb controls and used the property bag and all but just wasn't fresh on my mind again till now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is only one tip to be added to the accepted answer.

If you need to replace any **generic** VB control with 3rd party or custom ActiveX control you must replace the:

```
BeginProperty Font
```

with

```
BeginProperty Font {0BE35203-8F91-11CE-9DE3-00AA004BB851}
```

Omiting to do so results with **run-time error 713** when trying to edit/open the form.

If there is no BeginProperty statement in the block then control uses default font and this replacement is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

An additional scenario to look for is if the classes in the OCX are referenced directly in code.

In other words, if the control class was `ABCButton` then you need to look for `ABCButton` in all `.BAS` and `.CLS` files as well, and make appropriate changes.